# Returning a value from async callback in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, mvvm, asynchronous

My WPF application with the MVVM pattern shall basically perform the following:

- Button view binds to a command in the view model. --> Check!
- Command in view model asynchronously queries a webservice for a list of `CProject` objects for putting it into a `ProjectList` property. --> Check!

This looks like this...

**Command in the view model:**

```
proxy = new SomeService();
proxy.GetProjectList(GetProjectListCallback, username, password);
```

**Callback in the view model:**

```
private void GetProjectListCallback(object sender, GetProjectListCompletedEventArgs e) {
  this.ProjectList = e.Result;
}
```

`SomeService` implements an interface `ISomeService`.

```
public void GetProjectList(EventHandler<GetProjectListCompletedEventArgs> callback, string username, string password) {
  service.GetProjectListCompleted += callback;
  service.GetProjectListAsync(username, password);
}
```

So far this works fine. However I feel that I would like to move this callback to the service itself so that the view model only calls something like:

```
proxy = new SomeService();
this.ProjectList = proxy.GetProjectList(username, password);
```

But when moving the callback to the service how could it return `e.Result` to the calling view model? Or would using a `Task` a better idea?

Comment: Are you using VS2012? What .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Yes, I am using VS 2012. The target framework should be at least .NET 4. However 4.5 would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to re-create your WCF service proxy with VS2012. This [will change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx) your asynchronous method signatures to be something like:

```
Task<MyProjectList> GetProjectListAsync(string username, string password);
```

and your command becomes:

```
proxy = new SomeService();
this.ProjectList = await proxy.GetProjectListAsync(username, password);
```

---

If you don't want to re-create your WCF service proxy (it will update *all* your method signatures), then you [can wrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx) the [`Begin*`/`End*` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) as such:

```
public static Task<MyProjectList> GetProjectListTaskAsync(this SomeService @this, string username, string password)
{
  return Task<MyProjectList>.Factory.FromAsync(@this.BeginGetProjectList, @this.EndProjectList, username, password, null);
}
```

I have a full example of this kind of wrapping [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html).

or the existing [`*Async`/`*Completed` members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) as such:

```
public static Task<MyProjectList> GetProjectListTaskAsync(this SomeService @this, string username, string password)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MyProjectList>();
  EventHandler<GetProjectListCompletedEventArgs> callback = null;
  callback = args =>
  {
    @this.GetProjectListCompleted -= callback;
    if (args.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
    else if (args.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
    else tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
  };
  @this.GetProjectListCompleted += callback;
  @this.GetProjectListAsync(username, password);
}
```

Comment: I go with recreating all service calls to use the `Task` implementation. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't return a value from an asynchronous operation like that - you'd have to block that thread to wait for it to complete, which rather defeats the object of what you're doing. You always need a callback or continuation of some kind to run when the result is available. In C# 5 the `async`/`await` syntax does a lot of the plumbing for that for you, but ultimately it's still doing that under the hood, using things like `Task.ContinueWith`.

Without involving TPL and without having a C# 5 compiler available, the pattern you're using at the moment looks like a good one to me, if you're happy with the asynchronous operations that WCF provides.

In my own code I've previously built things a bit differently - using synchronous WCF operations called from threads on the threadpool, with the concurrency and callbacks managed by Reactive Extensions. However, the effect is much the same, it's all down to what kind of syntax and conceptual model you want. Using Rx is a natural fit for an application which is already built using a lot of Rx kit, because it keeps us in the same domain of `IObservable` being how data gets moved around.